# What is the reason Microsoft don't guarantee the implementation of Random class to remain the same across version of .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, random, versioning

Quoted from [online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Notes to Callers: The implementation of the random number generator in
>   the Random class is not guaranteed to remain the same across major
>   versions of the .NET Framework. As a result, your application code
>   should not assume that the same seed will result in the same
>   pseudo-random sequence in different versions of the .NET Framework.

What is the reason Microsoft don't guarantee the implementation of Random class to remain the same across version of .NET? More specifically, what is the reason Microsoft don't guarantee the same seed to produce the same sequence of random numbers across major version of .NET framework?

Comment: You can't change it, so what does it matter? If your application depends solely on the output of this, then you have yourself a greater problem.

Comment: They are reserving the right to change the RNG.

Comment: They want to be able to change the implementation at any time to a better one? (as in time and/or code complexity)

Comment: Better question is why would they?

Comment: Might be interesting and related: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulg_AHBOIQU  Perhaps the reason is "in case the US government wants it changed?"  Anyway, I have no idea if .NET uses the random number generation from this video, but it's interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Any reason to guarantee this?

Comment: Take a look at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634761/system-random-serious-bug (bugged generator due to a typo): should they leave the generator bugged for compatibility? :)

Comment: @loreb: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/222978/113457.

Comment: @StiffJokes interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a problem with the highly upvoted post.  The Random class most certainly generates predictable numbers.  From the documentation for the Random(Int32) constructor:

> Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers.

What Microsoft does *not* want to promise is that this sequence will be identical in another .NET Framework release.  There's a good reason for that, they cannot be sure if the algorithm they used is *completely* free of flaws.  The kind that makes code that uses the Random class vulnerable or liable to generate biased results.  Odds are very low but not zero.

There is precedent for this, the most infamous case was a problem with the random generator that IBM used in their mainframe software, called [RANDU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU).  Quoted as "Widely considered to be one of the most ill-conceived random number generators ever designed".  It has pretty obvious flaws once analysts started to take a better look at it.  First flagged in 1963, it was still widely used in the 1970s.

Comment: Is it possible to change the algorithm (to boast its performance for example) but keep the output unchanged? (Note that I am a newbie in this field)

Comment: The Random class _does_ generate predictable numbers (i.e. _pseudo_ random), but it's _not its main purpose_. So one can assume the .Net team has no actual reason to spend time making the generated numbers the same for a given seed value between different .Net versions.

Answer (score 14):

Because generating predictable numbers is not the purpose of the `Random` class.

It's purpose is to generate pseudo-random numbers:

> Represents a pseudo-random number generator, a device that produces a sequence of numbers that meet certain statistical requirements for randomness.

The way the numbers are generated is an **implementation detail**. If they find a better or faster way to do it, they want to reserve the right to change it, and give you the fair warning not to produce code that relies on it.

Comment: But I am still confused with why Microsoft made the current implementation produce the same sequence of numbers for the same seed.

Comment: @StiffJokes - That's how seeds work. The RNG extrapolates a pseudo random number by putting the seed value into a formula.